Gitlab Runner UI stuck
my gitlab cicd runner is starting and at end , it is stucking without showing me the result till the timeout, and after it it is failing with timeout error
when I see for that process while that job is running inside the machine, and in /proc/process_id/fd/, able to see the result,
why UI is getting stuck and connection between gitlab and gitlab ci is failing?
Current runner version : 13.8, and also upgraded to latest,.
Sometimes it is working and sometimes it is not,
There is no issue with infrastructure.
This is my gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
        - jira_verification_merge
        - npm_test

before_script:
  - export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  - '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # Load nvm'
  - '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # Load nvm bash_completion'  

variables:
  NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=16384"    

jira_verification_merge:
  stage: jira_verification_merge
  tags:
    - jira
  only: [merge_requests]
  script:
    - python3 /home/gitlab-runner/jira-ci-scripts/verify_tickets_in_commits.py 

npm_test:
  stage: npm_test
  tags:
    - npm
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - date
    - node --version
    - npm --version
    - rm -rf ../myproject-ui-variables ; git clone --depth 1 https://oauth2:$GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.myproject.com/my-grp-eng/myproject-ui-variables.git ../myproject-ui-variables
    - npm run build ; cd ../myproject-ng-runtime 
    - npm install 
    - npm i yalc -g
    - yalc add @myproject/variables
    - bash bundle-runtime-cli.sh
    - npm run test 
  retry:
        max: 2
        when: stuck_or_timeout_failure


there are two runners I am using , and after first one completing only second one staring, based on tags and installed it on ubuntu 22

Is it self hosted? Show the .gitlab-ci.yml
With the given information it is only possible to guess

yes, it is self hosted and I updated my question with .gitlab-ci.yml on it

@Ganesh which job is affected by this?

@MichaelKotzjan, npm_test this job and at the command , npm run test is failing, sometimes I observed, at the starting of this job also it is getting failing... which is associated with the tag npm

@Ganesh so what happens if you add something like echo "npm_test finished" at the end of npm_test? Could it be that the command npm run test gets stuck, not the runner? If that's the case you would not see the output from echo

@MichaelKotzjan, I added echo at the end of the npm_test, but still the npm run test getting stuck, it is not showing output from echo. Also I can see the echo in /proc/<process_id>/fd/<file> , which is the output of the process., Didn't understood the behavour.
